# Как спарсить числовые значения и произвести над ними сложение?

Tags: c#, парсер, visual-studio-2013, htmlagilitypack

Подскажите, как через HtmlAgilityPack спарсить определенный текст, переконвертировать их в числа с отсечением последнего символа, и просуммировать.
Вот тут [код](http://pastebin.com/8Hhk9vtV) html страницы. Парсить нужно строки такого вида

```
<td align="right">258955b</td>
```

Хочу через HtmlAgilityPack написать в c#

Comment: Всё очень просто: нужно начать и закончить. Что уже сделано?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функции тебе

```
/// <summary>
/// Получает HTML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <returns>Возвращает всю HTML страницу в формате string</returns>
public string getRequest(string url = "http://www.example")
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = null;

        if (response.CharacterSet == null)
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        }
        else
        {
            readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.Default); //Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)
        }

        string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        return data;
    }
    return null;
}

/// <summary>
/// Возврвщвет список
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<string> GetDataFromInternet()
{

    try
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        string requestHTML = getRequest(); // или же укажешь свой файл 

        doc.LoadHtml(requestHTML);
        HtmlNodeCollection c = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/li/div/span");
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count-1; i += 6)
        {
            list.Add(c[i].InnerText);
            j++;
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

`GetDataFromInternet` – вернет тебе листом все твои значения. `Convert.ToSingle("12312")` - конвертирует строку в число.